# mvc PagedList.IPagedList view want to print with all Records

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a mvc view with PagedList.IPagedList .I want to wprint this page using window.print in print button click.

But when i print its show only the current page how many value is there

in each page it 10 is the page count mention .

is it possible to get all the record approching this way ?

Comment: You need to provide some code for us to look at. Otherwise we will not be able to help you, as StackOverflow is not a tutorial site or a site to do stuff instead of you. It is a site to help you correct your errors and wrong assumptions (and of course in the end achieve what you wanted.)

Comment: <div class="pagination">
                            Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber)
                            of @Model.PageCount   @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("List", new { page }))
                        </div>

Comment: then a button <button id="btnPrint" ></button>  in this button click calling the javascript    <script>
    $(function () {
        $("#btnPrint").click(function () {

          

            window.print();

       
        });
    });

</script>

Comment: this will print only the first page of the list . I want all the result from page need to print .